# Can't connect to Access Database from VBA query in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-2010

I have a VBA query built in excel that runs a SQL query against an Access Database. The connection works when the database is unprotected without a password using the following code:

```
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Cnct = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Cnct = Cnct & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct
```

But when I password protect the database and try the same above but with added password condition, it won't connect and I get a "Run-time error -2147217843" message. The code I'm using for this is as follows:

```
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Cnct = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Cnct = Cnct & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Cnct = Cnct & "user ID=" & Environ("Username") & ";"
Cnct = Cnct & "password=XXXXXXXXXX;"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Some one will probably spot this straight away but what is in Environ("Username") at run time? and then can you manually log into the db using the value in Environ("Username") and the password?

Comment: When i open the database it only asks for a password. Do I even need the username piece? I got Environ("Username") from internet, it supposedly grabs the windows login username.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ - See the comments under *Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0* RE encryption with Access 2010

Comment: Thanks Alex, do you know how to set the encryption settings to the 2007 encryption?

Comment: The database is looking for the database userid and password, not the windows userid (which is returned by Environ("Username")  ) .   If it only asks for a password, the **UserID is likely `admin`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the connection string to use when you have an Access 2007 -
>   2013 database protected with a password using the "**Set Database
>   Password**" function in Access.
>
> ```
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
> ```
>
> Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also
>   that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems,
>   try change password to a short one with normal characters.
>
> **Note!** Reports say that a database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme does not work with this connection
>   string. In Access; try options and choose 2007 encryption method
>   instead. That should make it work. We do not know of any other
>   solution. Please get in touch if other solutions is available!

([Source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/))